# Installing CodeIgniter4 inside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

So i want to add a crud system with CI4 to an existing wordpress site. So I moved my CI4 inside my website root folder. Looks like this

```
--web (root folder)
|
 --wp-admin
 --wp-content
 --project (CI4 folder)
 |
  --App
  --...
```

The problem is I cant access the project. It supposed to be in mywebsite.com/project (right?).
The page says

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

I already change the following line in App.php in project/app/config

```
public $baseURL = 'mywebsite.com/';
```

So I search about this problem and found out few articles about wordpress .htaccess prevent this. I tried to change the .htaccess in wordpress from

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

to this one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but i realize that ci4 dont have index.php in the main folder anymore.

so my questions are:

1. For the ci4 configuration, what i need to change in ci4 files other than the line in app.php above?
2. For the 404 Forbidden problem (I'm guessing it has something to do with .htaccess)
3. Any suggestions to make this work, even if it has nothing to do with the .htaccess

a briefly explanation will help too. Thanks!

Comment: You probably have seen this https://www.cometchat.com/blog/how-to-integrate-codeigniter-with-wordpress `by installing a Runkit PHP extension, we can overwrite the global function, provided that we have both site_url functions for WordPress and CodeIgniter in separate directories.` Not sure if this technique still works.

Comment: Those instructions are specifically for CI3 and a lot has changed between 3 and 4. Some concepts are still relevant in principle, e.g. bootstrapping the framework. If you don't actually need to use CodeIgniter as a "full" framework (i.e. you *just* want the CRUD functionality of a database), CI4 might be a little "fat" for your purposes. I personally get a big laugh when anyone calls it a "lightweight...framework".

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. Just move the index.php and the .htaccess file in the public folder to ci4 root folder and then open the index.php file and edit this line

```php
require realpath(FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php') ?: FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

To

```php
require realpath(FCPATH . './app/Config/Paths.php') ?: FCPATH . './app/Config/Paths.php';
```

I hope this help else call my attentions